# Remove context menu / right click in a Ext JS grid

Tags: extjs

I have a table grid in Ext Js with a selection.CheckboxModel
I can multi select items in the grid, but it seems like also right click can select items

The question is is there any way to remove right click so it does not select item/s?

Thanks in advance,
Bob

Answer (score 2):

To prevent selection with rigth button you can use this code (with Ext JS 4)...

```
var allowSelection=true;
```

...

```
grid.on('beforeitemmousedown', function(grid, record, item, index, event, eOpts) { 
    if (event.button==0) allowStreetSelection=true; else allowSelection=false; 
});

grid.on('beforeselect', function(grid, record, index, eOpts) { 
    return allowSelection; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop the context menu, you can catch the `rowcontextmenu` event and stop it.

```
grid.on('rowcontextmenu', function(grid,index,e) { e.stopEvent() });
```

This may also solve your row selection issue but right-click doesn't select rows for me. What version of ExtJS are you using and on which browsers do you see this problem?  On ExtJS 3.3 and Firefox 4 and IE 8-9 I can't reproduce it.

Edit: For Ext 4, [containercontextmenu](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-containercontextmenu) looks to be the event to catch. Returning false from that handler should stop the context menu from appearing. I don't have much experience with Ext 4, so let me know if it works for you.

Comment: The version is the 4.0.1 (latest stable). You can see it in action here: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/array-grid.html .. Try right click on any of the rows and a selection is made. I have not yet found a way to disable this behavior.

Comment: Bob, I poked around in the ExtJS 4 docs and found a likely candidate.

Comment: wes, Thanks! It is not the contextmenu that is the problem, but that it is possible to select using right click. I want to select n number of items, right click (using itemcontextmenu) and display my menu, but since right click also selects I loose my selection. I guess I can solve it with coding but I hoped it was possible to cancel the grid select when right clicking.

Answer (score 0):

We've also met the same problem while using ExtJS4, our solution for now is to modify the original code in extJS.

Find:

```
} else if (me.isSelected(record) && !e.shiftKey 
        && !e.ctrlKey && me.selected.getCount() > 1) 
{
    me.doSelect(record, keepExisting, false);
```

*You can find them in `ext-all.js` or in `src/selection/Model.js`*

And change it to:

```
} else if (me.isSelected(record) && !e.shiftKey && !e.ctrlKey && me.selected.getCount() > 1) {
    if (e.button != 0)
        keepExisting = true;
    else
        keepExisting = false;
    me.doSelect(record, keepExisting, false);
```

This code will prevent clear current item selections except u're clicking the item with mouse button 0 (left button).

Answer (score 0):

This worked like a charm for me (EXTJS 4.1.2):

```
grid.on('beforeitemmousedown', function(grid, record, item, index, event, eOpts) {
  return (event.button == 0);
});
```